# Internet Explorer, SVG and XHTML

Tags: internet-explorer, xhtml, svg

I'm trying to visualize an xhtml file, looks great on Webkit ( Chrome, Safari, iOS ) almost perfect in Firefox ( I'm curious about not rendering the second row problem also ) BUT the problem is always the same IE 8.0

Is trying to download the file, I did put an Iframe trying to, I don't know, avoid this but no fix on this, do you guys have an opinion on this issue?

http://bcndevcon.org/dev/infographic2/infographic.xhtml

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You might want to fix your broken css on lines 13 and 14 here: http://bcndevcon.org/dev/infographic2/css/main.css.

Comment: IE8 does not support SVG natively at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of IE are you using?

As far as I know, most versions of IE do not have support for SVG.

The W3C has a project called [Project SVG Plugin](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/wiki/SVG_Plugin_for_IE) for IE.

IE9 now natively supports SVG but no previous version does.

Comment: After over a decade of ignoring it, while every other browser supported it, Microsoft finally got wise and now supports SVG in IE9.

Comment: I cannot rely on people from IE 6.0 to IE 8.0 installing a plugin, so I probably go Flash.

Comment: Ironically Flash also requires a plugin...but I get your point, more people have the Flash plugin already installed.